# Read a File in Installshield and fill a form

Tags: installation, installshield, installshield-2014

Im trying to find the way to read/write a config file
using a C# library, Im running Installshield 2014 in Visual Studio 2013, 
I have already the dialog box.
I added a Custom Action of type= "Call a public method from in a managed assembly"
with the option "Installed with the product" and selected the primary output as the source targeting the class and method in question, but this is not working.
I don't know exactly what is wrong with it, the dialog should appear prior the installation. any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a debugging guideline, look at a verbose log. What I expect it will tell you in this case is that the assembly cannot be found. If so, this is likely because you say you are calling an assembly that will be installed with the product, well before said assembly has been installed. (There may or may not also be some issues with referencing an output group; I don't believe I've ever tried that.)

Depending on your needs you'll have to choose between two approaches:

- Reschedule the action so that the assembly is available, or
- Make the assembly available at its current scheduling by choosing a different location (such as the Binary table).